# ggplot2 geom_bar() , do not merge y-values shared same x-ids

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting a barplot using `ggplot` + `geom_bar()` function in R.

I have some the recoreds which share the same x-axis identifiers.

`geom_bar()` did merge all values that shared the same x-axis identifiers.

Like the following example.

```
library("ggplot2")

df <- data.frame(x = c("a","a","b","c","d","e"),
                 y = c(5,5,5,5,5,5),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

The erroneous graph is displayed below.

The highest bar means the sum of multiple y-values shared same x-axis names.

Anyone else could help me to solve this problem? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example so we can understand what's going on.

Comment: Interesting question. Your data is out of shape though - you cannot plot duplicate data points on an axis - how will anyone reading the plot know the difference between the two data points?

Comment: Finally， I solved it using `barplot()` function that does not merge values that have same x-axis name.

Answer (score 1):

As you seem to have surmised, the graph is not erroneous, but correct. You have a total of 10 for `a` and that's what it's showing. If you want it to ignore duplicate X-axis values then you need to tell ggplot which datapoints it should actually be using. `barplot()` is assuming that your duplicate `a` values are intentional, ggplot assumes they should be grouped. These are both reasonable assumptions and it's your responsibility to determine beforehand which is correct.